# Need a mysql query fetching the result by grouping and with condition

Tags: mysql

i need to fetch all the columns by grouping fid and where the status fields of the fid need to be 1

```
id fid status
1   1    1
2   1    0
3   2    1
4   2    1
5   3    0
6   4    1
```

in the above table i need to fetch the fid by grouping fid and status of all the grouped rows must be 1
here the result will be  2, 4

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please update with the query you tried, the result you get and the expected result.

Comment: try this `SELECT fid,status FROM feed where status=1 group by fid;` it will return `1,2,4` from FID

Comment: The question is to get the `fid`s for which all `status` values are 1. [In given e.g.: 2, 4]. But @sethuraman, you could have tried it out and posted that query.

Comment: I tried this query "SELECT fid FROM my_table where status = 1 GROUP BY fid"

This query returns the 1,2,4 but i need the result as 2,4 which has the status as 1 in all the rows

Comment: @sethuraman - I have already added my answer below, which produces [2, 4].

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT fid, status FROM `table_name` WHERE status=1 GROUP BY fid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT status, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id) ids, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fid) fids
FROM yourTable
WHERE status=1 -- remove this condition if you want to have the fids where the status is 0 too
GROUP BY status;
```

See [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) for insight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    reqd_stat.fid1
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        fid fid1, COUNT(*) stat
    FROM
        stk_grp
    GROUP BY fid1) all_stats
    JOIN (SELECT 
        fid fid2, COUNT(*) stat1
    FROM
        stk_grp
    WHERE
        status = 1
    GROUP BY fid2) pos_stats ON pos_stats.fid2 = all_stats.fid1
    HAVING pos_stats.stat1 = all_stats.stat) reqd_stat;
```

Explaination:

1. `all_stats` table will group on `fid` without any condition
2. `pos_stats` table will group on `fid` with `status=1` condition
3. `having` is used to compare the count of status column (if they are equal, then all `fid`s belonging to that group have `status=1`)
4. Just print the `fid` to get desired output